How do you create multiple test override tasks in a build.gradle.kts for different JUnit5 Tags
In this question
JUnit 5 test suite choose test methods
its shown how to do it in Gradle using the Groovy language...
How would that translate into the equivalent for a build.gradle.kts file...
Say we had tests denoted with @Tag("Type1")   and @Tag("Type2")
And I want to create 2 custom tasks
run_type2_tests and run_type1_tests

Please provide the code you have so far as a [mre].

To register a new Gradle task use tasks.register like described in the Gradle docs. For a testing task use the built-in task type Test:
tasks.register<Test>("run_type1_tests"){
}

Then configure included tags via Test.useJUnitPlatform:
useJUnitPlatform {
    includeTags("Type1")
}

Final result:
tasks.register<Test>("run_type1_tests") {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags("Type1")
    }
}

tasks.register<Test>("run_type2_tests") {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags("Type2")
    }
}


I'v got an error Cannot invoke "org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection.getAsFileTree()" because the return value of "org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.getTestClassesDirs()" is null (using gradle 8.7)

With these exact tasks? Is it a KMP app? @YuraShinkarev

I recommend using the JVM Test Suite Plugin.
Each JvmTestSuite has a collection of targets. You can register a new target, each with a specific combination of JUnit tags.
//build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    `java`
    `jvm-test-suite`
}


@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
testing {
    suites {
        // get the default test suite
        val test by suites.getting(JvmTestSuite::class) {

            // modify the regular test task to _only_ run not-Type1 and not-Type2 tests
            targets.named("test") {
                testTask.configure {
                    description = "Runs tests without Type1 or Type2 tags"
                    useJUnitPlatform {
                        excludeTags.addAll("Type1", "Type2")
                    }
                }
            }

            // Create a new target for _only_ running tests tagged as Type1
            targets.register("testType1") {
                testTask.configure {
                    description = "Runs Type1 tests"
                    useJUnitPlatform {
                        includeTags.addAll("Type1")
                    }
                }
            }

            // Create a new target for _only_ running tests tagged as Type2
            targets.register("testType2") {
                testTask.configure {
                    description = "Runs Type2 tests"
                    useJUnitPlatform {
                        includeTags.addAll("Type2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Make sure that custom tests don't get missed and run all tests when running check
tasks.check {
    dependsOn(testing.suites)
}

